# grails ajax file upload in a g:form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I have a form which is in a modal window, as part of this form I have a file upload.

I am struggling to find a way to upload in the

```
 <g:form>
```

via Ajax. I know I can use uploadForm, but this refreshes the page which is not what I want.

I have tried all the ajax file upload grails plugins with no luck.

Can anyone point me to some sort of way I can do this.

What I have tried so for is as follows:

```
    <g:form action="save">

           <g:textField name="category" value=""/>

                  <g:uploadForm name="myUpload">
                         <input type="file" name="myFile" />
                  </g:uploadForm>

           <g:submitButton name="create"value="create" />


     </g:form>

     <g:javascript>
           $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('#myUpload').ajaxForm(function() {
                 alert("File upload finished!");
                 });
            });
     </g:javascript>
```

The alert never get triggered. 
I have added the relevant JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ajaxify your upload form using the [jquery ajax form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

If you want to submit everything in your form in one go via ajax, you can do something like this:

```
<g:uploadForm name="myUpload" action="save">
    <g:textField name="category" value=""/>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <g:submitButton name="create"value="create" />
</g:uploadForm>

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#myUpload').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("File upload finished!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Worldwide usage has [dropped to 10%](http://theie8countdown.com/). Where does it say in the question that support for IE8 is a requirement?

Comment: I was just wondering, cause I had the same problem and there was need to support ie8.

Comment: Unfortunately with IE8 you'll need to use a hidden iframe. There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/).

Comment: Yes, I did it using iframe.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as it need to be part of an existing form as far as im aware you cant have a form inside a form. I will edit my original question and add more code.

Comment: No, you can't nest forms. Just replace your outer <g:form> with a <g:uploadForm> and put all the <g:input> fields in that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to set up the form if you want to submit everything via ajax (the regular form fields, and the file you're uploading). If you just want to upload the file via ajax, you'll need to create a separate uploadForm (outside of your existing form).